# Jquery Ajax XML respond problem

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I am a little bit confused on something, see I am doing an Ajax request via Jquery, I send back encoded data in an xml document ( using htmlentities to prevent XSS ) but the thing is when I parse the XML and get the data it seems Jquery automatically decodes the htmlentities and I end up with vulnerable data.

Do you have any idea how to prevent Jquery from decoding the encoded data, or I am missing an option in the ajax request.

Any help is very appreciated as I am stuck at this point.

here is my current ajax options :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax_handle.php',
  data: {pg: cpage, rid: rid},
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
     $( button ).val( 'Error' );
  },
  success: function(xmldata){ /* Parsing here */ }
}
```

Somehow When I use Jquery find() and get the text, all the data that has been encoded with htmlentities gets decoded.

Example :

```
Data : <c><cu>Test</cu><cb>&#160;htmlentitiesgez564&lt;script&gt;</cb></c>
```

Parsed data :

```
cu : Test
cb :  htmlentitiesgez564<script>;
```

You can see how dangerous that can be, any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Please edit your question: Indent source code with 4 spaces to have it look good.

Comment: You mean the xmldata you get in the success function has already the decoded entities? Did you try explicitly setting dataType to xml in the ajax request?

Comment: I did, still the same, what I understood is that Jquery automatically decodes the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is automatically decoding the data but as long as you don't `eval` or inject that data into the DOM nothing will happen. So for example if you wanted to inject this into the DOM you don't have to use the [html](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) method but the [text](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text#val) method:

```
$('#someDiv').text('<script>alert("ok");</' + 'script>');
```

Comment: Thank you! That's actually a much simpler way to do it, I love K.I.S.S

Comment: Also I have figured out that putting your data inside <![CDATA[ ] ]> prevents the parser from parsing your data, so this as well solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

try adding the dataType option to your ajax config object

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax_handle.php',
  data: {pg: cpage, rid: rid},
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: "text",
  cache: false,
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
     $( button ).val( 'Error' );
  },
  success: function(xmldata){ /* Parsing here */ }
}
```

This should tell jQuery that the received response is to be interpreted as text

Comment: That's true, but I won't be able to parse it, since the respond is XML data.